# Admin search not working for my fields - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset

I have a model with an encrypted field.

So fields are encrypted and decrypted as they enter and leave the database.

---

## The problem:

within the admin panel

- **?q='item'** does not seem to find any rows
- **?field_name='item'** does find them all!!

---

Any ideas? :)

Comment: And show us how you define the search fields in the admin as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you would have to encrypt the search term as well to fit to the entries in the database. This will most probably fail with the standard admin functionality, since all the fields specified as search fields will be handled in the same fashion. You would have to create your own `ChangeList` class and override its [`get_query_set`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py#L165) method, so that it can handle your field in a special way!

Comment: Thanks for this!!! :) I'm a bit confused how to use ChangeList though? Easiest way to hack this I can think of is to remove the field from search_list and add another search field for the encrypted field... :) any ideas?